# Whereto with `disableDeprecatedForms(),provideForms()` in RC5?

Tags: forms, angular, observable

Without deactivating the old forms with (in RC4 > it was a part of bootstrapping process)

```
disableDeprecatedForms(),
provideForms()
```

I cannot render data (got over observables) e.g. in a select boxes (options/*ngFor).

**Where can I deactivate the old forms in RC5?**

(OverviewComponent below has the form with select boxes)

That's the new **main.ts**:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

That's the new **app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

import {
  OverviewComponent,
} from './forms/index';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OverviewComponent,
    BasisdateneingabeComponent
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: What's the question or problem?

Comment: selectboxes are not filled and there is no error message

Comment: have you tried subscribing the observable

Comment: I can't see any select boxes in your question.

Comment: I want to deactivate the old forms and I think that is the cause of the problem. Because: before I've deactivated them in RC4 I had similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9813#issuecomment-231169231), `disableDeprecatedForms()` still exists in RC5 but has been deprecated. Your problems are probably coming from the fact that your application is using the RC4 forms API. The best solution would be to update your forms to RC5 avoid further problems with new releases.

In lieu of that, [you should be able to find a fix here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9732) (Bootstrapping has changed a little bit since that was written). There is a  `DeprecatedFormsModule` that you can use. In your `app.module`, import it and add it to the imports array. Like so:

```
//...
import {DeprecatedFormsModule} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  //...
  imports: [
   //....
   DeprecatedFormsModule
  ],
  //...
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, where can I find a compare (list) between RC4- and RC5-Forms-API ?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a thing. You can look at Angular's updated [guide for template driven forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) and compare that next to the [old version](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms-deprecated.html). For dynamic forms: [new version](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html) vs [old version](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form-deprecated.html). The differences aren't actually significant, at least on the surface.

Comment: How can I still be using the deprecated forms in rc5 when I am not even importing DeprecatedFormsModule?